# Angular 7 - Save register by id using radio button

Tags: angular

This is my html code:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let new of data">
  <div
    class="col-md-12 col-xl-12 col-sm-12"
    [ngClass]="{ divSelected: new.idcontentnew == idSelected }"
  >
    <div class="form-group">
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="inputIdNew{{ new.idcontentnew }}"
        name="inputIdNew"
        [(ngModel)]="inputIdUpdate"
        [value]="new.idcontentnew"
        (click)="selected(new.idcontentnew)"
      />
      <label for="id">Select notice</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input
        type="text"
        id="inputTitle{{ new.idcontentnew }}"
        name="inputTitle{{ new.idcontentnew }}"
        [(ngModel)]="new.title"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input
        type="text"
        id="inputText{{ new.idcontentnew }}"
        name="inputText{{ new.idcontentnew }}"
        [(ngModel)]="new.text"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xl-12 col-sm-12">
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-outline-dark"
      (click)="save(inputIdNew, new)"
    >
      Save
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the "save" button I pass the parameters of the id value of the selected radio button, but I do not know how to pass it an object that will contains the data that I am going to modify and save, of the id selected with the radio button.

This is the ts code

```
save(id: number, userItem: NewsModel) {
     this.newRegistry.idcontentnew = id;
     this.newRegistry.text = 'aaaaa';// should contain the text model value in base to the selected radio button
     this.newRegistry.title = 'bbbbbb'; // should contain the title model value in base to the selected radio button
     this.homeService.save(this.newRegistry)
       .subscribe(
         data => this.route.navigate(['/home']),
         error => this.loginService.closeLogin()
       );
}
```

How I could do it? thanks,

Comment: It should just be `this.newRegistry.text = userItem.text` from what I understand. But maybe you should read more about ReactiveForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your html like this.
you can set full object as input value by changing

```
<input type="radio" id="inputIdNew{{new.idcontentnew}}" name="inputIdNew" [(ngModel)]="inputIdUpdate" [value]="new.idcontentnew" (click)="selected(new.idcontentnew);" /> <label for="id">Select notice</label>
```

to

```
<input type="radio" id="inputIdNew{{new.idcontentnew}}" name="inputIdNew" [(ngModel)]="inputIdUpdate" [value]="new" (click)="selected(new.idcontentnew);" /> <label for="id">Select notice</label>
```

Now change the button function reference here.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="save(inputIdNew, inputIdUpdate);">Save</button>
```

full code

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let new of data">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xl-12 col-sm-12" [ngClass]="{'divSelected': new.idcontentnew == idSelected}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="radio" id="inputIdNew{{new.idcontentnew}}" name="inputIdNew" [(ngModel)]="inputIdUpdate" [value]="new" (click)="selected(new.idcontentnew);" /> <label for="id">Select notice</label>
            </div>           
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="inputTitle{{new.idcontentnew}}" name="inputTitle{{new.idcontentnew}}" [(ngModel)]="new.title" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="inputText{{new.idcontentnew}}" name="inputText{{new.idcontentnew}}" [(ngModel)]="new.text" />
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xl-12 col-sm-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="save(inputIdNew, inputIdUpdate);">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

now you can get your userItem here just as before

```
save(id: number, userItem: NewsModel) {
     this.newRegistry.idcontentnew = id;
     this.newRegistry.text = 'aaaaa';// should contain the text model value in base to the selected radio button
     this.newRegistry.title = 'bbbbbb'; // should contain the title model value in base to the selected radio button
     this.homeService.save(this.newRegistry)
       .subscribe(
         data => this.route.navigate(['/home']),
         error => this.loginService.closeLogin()
       );
}
```

Comment: good idea, how I did not realize before, working ok, thanksss